# Easiest/quickest way to implement URL rewrite in Coldfusion 10

Tags: coldfusion, url-rewriting, coldfusion-10

I would simply like URLS that are in the format www.mysite.com/blog to be rewritten to www.mysite.com/blog.cfm.

So, another example:

```
www.mysite.com/contact
```

would be rewritten as:

```
   www.mysite.com/contact.cfm
```

What is the easiest and quickest way to implement this sort of url rewriting in Coldfusion 10 running Tomcat? Google seems to offer an array of complicated options and pages and people struggling with this, so I'm just wondering if there is a basic way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Tomcat as a webserver? You don't have Apache or IIS in front of it?

Comment: @SeanCoyne: The website currently does not go through IIS, although it could if absolutely necessary. However, I'd prefer not to - simply for avoiding adding extra complications in the setup of the website.

Comment: It's not required.  I just can't answer the question if I don't have the whole picture.

Comment: @SeanCoyne: I can understand that. I thought I had given all the info - I did mention that it runs on Tomcat though. Thanks!

Comment: I know you did, however, to my knowledge, almost NO ONE runs it using only Tomcat.  Most run a web server of some kind in front of Tomcat using the connector supplied by Adobe.  Just wanted to confirm since it is an atypical setup.

Comment: @SeanCoyne: I see - thanks for clarifying. Well the reason I left it ou is because when I develop locally I don't use IIS for the website in question. I simply access it via localhost:8500/mysite - however, IIS is running - I just prefer not to use it if not necessary - I don't know if that clarifies things a bit better. IF it's necessary to accomplish this, then I have no choice I guess.

Comment: _"to my knowledge, almost NO ONE runs it using only Tomcat."_ - so why don't you publish the results of the survey you did on all JVM powered websites? Because without objective data that's just an anecdotal statement. **If Tomcat's Coyote web server provides all the functionality needed, there's no _need_ to add something else in front.** (Of course, decent URL rewriting is a functionality many people need, so a reason to use something in front, if Tuckey doesn't satisfy that need.)

Comment: Jeez, get a grip.  I said, "to my knowledge", its clearly an anecdotal statement, and of course there is no need to run anything else in front of Tomcat/Coyote. In addition, I certainly was not extending my statement to "all JVM powered websites" sorry if it wasn't clear I was referring to ColdFusion.  Figured the whole "using the connector supplied by Adobe" covered that part, but I guess not, my bad.

Comment: If "of course there's no need" then it wouldn't be such a common misunderstanding that one was needed - which is all I'm trying to clarify here. (You called it an "atypical setup" and capitalised "no one", both of which are counter to it being a limited/subjective experience, and thus why I wanted to clarify it.)

Comment: My reference to all JVM powered websites is because that's where Tomcat is relevant. CF10 is the first version to use it (and as an aside, recommending against using JRun's JWS web server directly would be valid). When it comes to deciding whether Coyote is a valid choice the greater experience of Tomcat users is more likely to be useful than the relevatively limited experience of CF users. (And looking at what the rest of the JVM world is something CF devs should be doing more of.)

Answer (score 0):

I have used the [Tuckey UrlRewriteFilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) in the past with Tomcat, works great.